# What is the openssl command line to decrypt text encrypted by this php snippet?

Tags: php, openssl

What is the openssl command line for decrypting text encrypted using the following php code?

```
function encrypt($text, $key) {
    return trim(base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $text, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB), MCRYPT_RAND))));
}
```

This is how far I got:

"blah blah" encrypted with "password" becomes:

```
whSklKP6+wJdbGpiaCavFp8BiaZ6B1LZmJ0d7Nqx2nc=
```

I try and decrypt this with:

```
openssl base64 -d -in test.b64 > test.bin
openssl enc -d -aes-256-ecb -pass pass:password -in test.bin -out test.txt
```

And I get:

```
bad magic number
```

Comment: It also need IV to be supplied with OpenSSL command.

Comment: I was entering the password interactively. Do I need to pass an IV and a password? If so how do I generate the IV? I'll update the question to show I'm using a password.

Comment: Sounds like the IV should be automatically derived from the password and input. http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/29106/openssl-recover-key-and-iv-by-passphrase